# Google Map Embed - 2 targets / 2 pins just can see one

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have problem with Google Map embed.

I want it have 2 pins (below) and it shows up with one pin:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xMVP.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sjBM.png]

This is what I did with it:

HTML

```
<iframe id="maps" scrolling="yes" src="https://www.google.ca/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=http:%2F%2Fmapsengine.google.com%2Fmap%2Fu%2F0%2Fkml%3Fmid%3DznCNeZskEW3Y.kS90qBvIE6qE%26amp%3Blid%3DznCNeZskEW3Y.kiLNrr6FIbEE&amp;aq=&amp;sll=51.022835,-114.12811&amp;sspn=0.070293,0.154324&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=51.022826,-114.128036&amp;spn=0.051829,0.109863&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```

And Javascript:

```
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;
  $('#maps').css('height', h - 100);
  $('#maps').css('width', w - 100);
  $('#maps').css('margin-left', 50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the zoom from 13 to 11 (zoom out to show both markers):

Your original "embed" URL (z=13):

https://www.google.ca/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=http:%2F%2Fmapsengine.google.com%2Fmap%2Fu%2F0%2Fkml%3Fmid%3DznCNeZskEW3Y.kS90qBvIE6qE%26amp%3Blid%3DznCNeZskEW3Y.kiLNrr6FIbEE&aq=&sll=51.022835,-114.12811&sspn=0.070293,0.154324&t=m&ie=UTF8&ll=51.022826,-114.128036&spn=0.051829,0.109863&z=13&output=embed

Change it to (z=11):

https://www.google.ca/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=http:%2F%2Fmapsengine.google.com%2Fmap%2Fu%2F0%2Fkml%3Fmid%3DznCNeZskEW3Y.kS90qBvIE6qE%26amp%3Blid%3DznCNeZskEW3Y.kiLNrr6FIbEE&aq=&sll=51.022835,-114.12811&sspn=0.070293,0.154324&t=m&ie=UTF8&ll=51.022826,-114.128036&spn=0.051829,0.109863&z=11&output=embed

Comment: That is a zero size div issue.  What determines the size of the div where it is being displayed?

Comment: Thank you much more @geocodezip. Because of your link - i think about embed the whole Google Map page with <object> and determine the width and height by using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone I found out the way to make it.

```
<object id="maps" type="text/html" data="https://www.google.ca/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=http:%2F%2Fmapsengine.google.com%2Fmap%2Fu%2F0%2Fkml%3Fmid%3DznCNeZskEW3Y.kS90qBvIE6qE%26amp%3Blid%3DznCNeZskEW3Y.kiLNrr6FIbEE&aq=&sll=51.022835,-114.12811&sspn=0.070293,0.154324&t=m&ie=UTF8&ll=51.022826,-114.128036&spn=0.051829,0.109863&z=13&output=embed">
```

I use object tag to show the whole page and use Javascript to fix the height and width for the map.

```
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;
  $('#maps').css('height', h - 100);
  $('#maps').css('width', w - 100);
  $('#maps').css('margin-left', 50);
```